# ArrayList <wrapper class> autocomplete in Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arraylist, autocomplete

I use IntelliJ IDEA to write Java and the autocomplete feature when creating an ArrayList has changed for some reason.
Started when I updated to v.2019.3, Build: 193.5233.102.

Before the update, after typing `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new` IntelliJ used to complete the line to:
 `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();`.
Since the update however, the line completes to `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();`.

How can I get it to autocomplete the way it was i.e. `ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>()`?

Comment: Why do you need to? The two statements are completely equivalent, but the second one is shorter. IntelliJ probably recognizes that and prefers autocompleting without the additional type, since it can be inferred.

Comment: @Glains: I just prefer the explicit declaration, + I'd like to know how/if it is possible to change this.

Comment: @Badda_Bing it is idiomatic to use the diamond operator (and has been since Java 7), because repeating the type information is redundant. Changing your ways can be hard, but perhaps embracing the (not very) new way of doing things could be better.

Comment: @Andy Turner: thank you Andy, I agree 100%. But is it even possible to change this? was the question...

Comment: @Badda_Bing have your searched the settings for "diamond operator"?

Comment: @Andy Turner: ah found it by searching 'diamond' in settings, million thanks Andy!

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash: I must wait 2 days before I can accept it, but I will. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy Turner for this one:
[image]